# Odd IP address when pinging my own computer

Tags: windows-vista, ping

When I ping a the computer I am using on my home network the response I get looks odd:

```
Reply from fe80::8150:b519:d5da:8a00%9: time<1ms
```

Yet I ping another computer on my home network and I get a normal IP address.

The results of ipconfig look like this:

```
Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::8150:b519:d5da:8a00%9
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.10.10.104
```

Is there anyway to get the ping results to display as IPv4?  And do the IPv6 results look normal?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

When you have IPv6 active, ping and a few other commands may default to IPv6. To force ping to use ipv4 add -4 as an argument:

```
ping localhost -4
```

Incidentally, you an also force IPv6 with -6

```
ping localhost -6
```

Answer (score 7):

Since others have gotten to the "get me back to IPv4" part of this question, I'll tackle the other bit.  I can't say I've seen many ipv6 addresses in the wild, so "look normal" ?  uh... let's google, shall we?

Here's a nice link on ["normal" IPv6 addresses](http://www.juniper.net/techpubs/software/erx/junose52/swconfig-routing-vol1/html/ipv6-config5.html):

> IPv6 addresses consist of eight hexadecimal groups. Each
>   hexadecimal group, separated by a colon (:), consists of
>   a 16-bit hexadecimal value. The following is an example
>   of the IPv6 format:

```
xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx
```

..and from [What Does an IPv6 Address Look Like?](http://www.opus1.com/ipv6/whatdoesanaddresslooklike.html):

> Colons separate 16-bit fields. Leading zeros can be omitted
>   in each field as can be seen above where the field :0003: is
>   written :3:. In addition, a double colon (::) can be used
>   once in an address to replace multiple fields of zeros. For
>   example:

```
fe80:0:0:0:200:f8ff:fe21:67cf
```

> can be written

```
fe80::200:f8ff:fe21:67cf
```

So your example is this:

```
fe80::8150:b519:d5da:8a00%9
```

According to A Dwarf, the %9 is a "zone index", "an identifier that helps transmitting packets across link-local addresses (when a host has more than one interface)".  So it's identifying the interface (NIC) received this packet, but not actually part of the IPv6 address.

The "::" means :0:, or :0:0:, or maybe more zeroes.  We don't know how many.  If we discard the %9, then we're looking at:

```
fe80::8150:b519:d5da:8a00
```

Since we know there's 8 groups of 4 hex digits, and we see only 5 groups above, we know there are three groups that the "::" needs to fill.  So the actual address is:

```
fe80:0000:0000:0000:8150:b519:d5da:8a00
```

Comment: The %9 prefix is the "zone index". An identifier that helps transmitting packets across link-local addresses (when a host has more than one interface). Here's the packet was sent to the zone index 9, which could be nic 9, for instance.

Comment: @A Dwarf thx for the insight!  adding to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Disable IPv6 on the network card.